# The insert statement conflicted with the Foreign Key SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, insert-update

I have searched the internet but couldn't find a solution. I am using the following SQL Statement in order to update some cells or create a new row:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PRCRDATALNS]

SET   FLD01 = :TIMX1 
     ,FLD02 = :TIML1

WHERE DIM1= :vmtrl AND PRCRULE= '2' AND LINENUM = '1'

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRCRDATALNS] (

       COMPANY 
      ,SODTYPE     
      ,SOTYPE
      ,PRCRULE
      ,DIM1
      ,DIM2
      ,DIM3
      ,PRCRDATALNS
      ,LINENUM
      ,FROMDATE
      ,FLD01
      ,FLD02
      ,SCALEQTY
      )

VALUES
        ('1'
        ,'13'
        ,'1'
        ,2
        ,:vmtrl
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'1'
        ,'1'
        ,GETDATE ( ) 
        ,:TIMX1
        ,:TIML1
        ,'1'
        );
```

When I execute it and a new row is to be inserted it says: `The insert statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "XD_PRCRDATALNS_PRCRULE". The conflict occurred in database "KOMBOS", table "dbo.PRCRDATA". The statement has been terminated.`

I am aware of what this means. First of all it isn't mentioned anything about issues in columns like others have. And secondly the table PRCRDATA has all the values that are needed like PRCRULE,SODTYPE,SOTYPE etc.

Where should I look at?

Comment: Firstly try to add record with this key to "dbo.PRCRDATA"

Comment: What do you mean with this key? I can insert rows to dbo.PRCRDATA with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed it down. The message from SQL Server was not right!
It was not PRCRULE the issue. The issue was the FROMDATE that was also a FK and I changed it from `GETDATE ()` to `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`  so I removed the time, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I cannot comment yet, so I need to post an "answer". I would suggest:

- Find out what column the FK violation appears against, by checking
  the source for dbo.PRCRDATA and what column has the
  XD_PRCRDATALNS_PRCRULE constraint.

  - Having done that you should now be able to see what value is the
    offending value in the INSERT statement.

Please let us know how it goes.

Niels

Comment: Please can you elaborate more because I am new to SQL Server. I have pressed the cross next to dbo.PRCDATA in folder `Columns` I saw that FK are COMPANY, SODTYPE, SOTYPE, PRCRULE.  in folder `Constraints` I see DF_PRCDATA_DIM1, DF_PRCDATA_DIM2, DF_PRCDATA_DIM3, DF_PRCDATA_LOCKID. All this info they do not tell me anything as the table PRCDATA does not have any cells empty...

Comment: OK, have a look at the definition of what a foreign key is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). So based on that what it means that some of the data you try to insert into [dbo].[PRCRDATALNS], has no corresponding values in dbo.PRCRDATA. You should be able to see what the ofending values are by looking at the FK definition, and see what columns they point to.